# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() Failling on IIS but not in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis

I have a page that makes a Async call to update a db record. After that call is made I rebind javascript to a textbox that is on the screen. In visual studio 2012 i have no issues it works like a charm. When i moved it live on iis 8. I get a exception below. This lives in the master page. Both the markup and the code behind are exactly the same as my VS environment. Any ideas on how i could troubleshoot this error? There are no console errors when this occurs.

```
   if (IsPostBack)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Editor", "loadEditor()", false);

        }
```

exception:

```
The script tag registered for type 'ASP.edit_default_aspx' and key 'editorScript' has invalid characters outside of the script tags: loadEditor(). Only properly formatted script tags can be registered.   at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.CheckScriptTagTweenSpace(RegisteredScript entry, String text, Int32 start, Int32 length)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.WriteScriptWithTags(HtmlTextWriter writer, String token, RegisteredScript activeRegistration)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RenderActiveScriptBlocks(List`1 updatePanels, HtmlTextWriter writer, String token, List`1 scriptRegistrations)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RenderActiveScripts(List`1 updatePanels, HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.ProcessScriptRegistration(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderPageCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control pageControl)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Load Editor function:

```
                function loadEditor() {

                    tinyMCE.init({....... });

                }
```

Comment: Try replacing loadEditor with <script type=\"text/javascript\">loadEditor();</script>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting in the script tags in your code.

```
if (IsPostBack)
{

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "Editor", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">loadEditor();</script>", false);

}
```